# How to call an array using a string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I would like to echo a bunch of arrays in numerical order, I tried using WHILE method but lacks the knowledge on how to combine strings to call a variable and get the value inside the array.

```
$ins1 = array ( 
              "select"  => array (  
                                   "1" => "1"
                                   ), 
              "note"  => array ( 
                                   "1" => "Message"
                                   )
              ); 

$ins2 = array ( 
              "select"  => array (  
                                   "1" => "2"
                                   ), 
              "note"  => array ( 
                                   "1" => "Sorry"
                                   )
              ); 


$count = 1;
while($count <= 2){
    $ins = '$ins'.$count;
    echo $ins["select"][$count] .' '. $ins["note"][$count].'<br>';
    $count++;
}
```

OUTPUT SHOULD BE:

```
1 Message
2 Sorry
```

Comment: What is the current output and what would you expect ?

Comment: So you only want to output the note if select is not 0? Also is the number in select the order of the messages or just numbers?

Comment: use $$ins (double $$)

Comment: Why don't you combine both `$ins1` and `$ins2` into an array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is "[Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)", through which you can set the variable name dynamically; so to get what you want, change your code as the following:

```
$count = 1;
while($count <= 2){
    $ins = 'ins'.$count;
    $var = $$ins; // now your $var is either $ins1 or $ins2 :)
    echo $var["select"][1] .' '. $var["note"][1].'<br>';
    $count++;
}
```

The output would be:

```
1 Message
2 Sorry
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have combined the two variable, and make life easier:

```
$ins = [
            [//$ins1
                "select"  => array ("1" => "1"), 
                "note"  => array ("1" => "Message" )
            ],
            [//$ins2
                "select" => array ("1" => "2"), 
                 "note"  => array ("1" => "Sorry")
            ]
        ]; 

for ($i = 0; $i < count($ins); $i++)
{
    echo $ins[$i]["select"][1]." ".$ins[$i]["note"][1]."<br/>";
}
```

for dynamic name of variables, see other answers.. hope i've helped you.. Cheers! ;)

Answer (score 0):

this will do the trick for you:

```
$ins1 = array ( 
              "select"  => array (  
                                   "1" => "1"
                                   ), 
              "note"  => array ( 
                                   "1" => "Message"
                                   )
              ); 

$ins2 = array ( 
              "select"  => array (  
                                   "1" => "2"
                                   ), 
              "note"  => array ( 
                                   "1" => "Sorry"
                                   )
              ); 


for($i=1; $i<1000; $i++) {

    $arr_name = 'ins'.$i;

    if(isset($$arr_name)) {

        $str = '';
        foreach ($$arr_name as $key => $value) {
            $str .= $value[1].' ';
        }
        echo trim($str).'<br/>';

    } else {
        break;
    }

}
```

Note: I have taken 1000 as a highest possible value, you can change accordingly. like in your case it is 2.